# Answer query from paypal

Tags: api, paypal

I have a form sending data to Paypal server.

```
`
<form id="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@testing.arm"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Credits"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="numbertovar"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://armbid.dev/credits/add"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://armbid.dev/credits/add"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"value="http://armbid.dev/credits/add"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Пополнить"/>
</form>`
```

After sending POST data to Paypal, user pays. And after his payment, I need in answer from paypal - transaction number, date of payment, amount payed.
At this moment I can send data to Paypal, pay, and go back

Comment: Someone help?..

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `Instant payment notifications` (callback URL) in paypal settings. It will be called by paypal after each transaction. And it will deliver this info to you